# 603 Decline when making outgoing call - twilio sip trunk

Tags: twilio

In regards to SIP trunking on twilio, which is utilized by a grandstream UCM ippbx.
Our account is fully verified by twilio and we are a legitimate business, however we do mask our office numbers with a generic "front desk" office number.

I am trying to call a number whose carrier resolves MCI Metro, ATS, Inc. (which looks to be a subsidiary of Verizon business)

Twilio is giving a 603 Decline sip response from the receiving carrier when we try to call the number.

I'm not sure what i can do to troubleshoot/solve this issue, since it seems list the calls are just being blocked by policy or blocklist, and since no details are given, i don't know what would need to be changed to get this call to complete.

Comment: Does dialing that same number outside Twilio (using your mobile phone for example) work?

Comment: Yes. (more character to allow comment)

Comment: Hmm, not much to go on here. I think the best thing to do is open a support ticket and provide the CallSID, so Twilio Support can dig into the issue and see what is happening on the carrier side. Ideally, if you can provide them 3 recent CallSID's less then 48 hours old, that is what they usually ask for for a carrier escalation.

Comment: @lemonskunnk got any solution?

Comment: I waited too long to submit the support request and they were unable to debug with the provided data - and since the error only occurred with one carrier I chose not to recreate the issue and troubleshoot any further.

Comment: Just for anyone who might be running into this as well, for us the issue was that the TwiML app wasn't getting the correct TwiML xml response from the defined Voice Request URL.